# In Rails, how can one move a "new" view for one model to a "show" view from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've been reading and watching videos on nested forms, but I haven't had any luck getting things working. (...and I know this just has to be incredibly easy...)

I have this view 'views/comments/new':

```
<% form_for([@job, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p>
<%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

...and I would like to move this form/text box to the 'jobs/show' view.

my job model:
job.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :assets
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

What I would like to do is have the form to add new comments at the bottom of the this job "show" page. Instead of going to "/jobs/15/comments/new", I would like to have the "new comment" form in the jobs show view.

How could I do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop that form code in comments/new right into the jobs/show view, but you need to make sure you define @comment in your controller.

jobs_controller.rb

```
def show
 @job = Job.find(params[:id])
 @comment = @job.comments.new
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
end
end
```

You'll probably want to make sure that the create action for comments redirects users back to the job, not the comment.

My personal recommendation would be to move that form to a partial, but if you're just getting started with rails this will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to show all comments for a job in the job show page, right?

If that's the case, I think the following code will do the job:

```
<% @job.comments.each do |comment| -%>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <p/>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Hi. I have that in thee jobs "show" view already.

<% @job.comments.each do |c| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
   <td>
    <p><%=h c.created_at %> <br /> <%= c.commenter %> said: <br /> <%=h c.body %></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>

What I would like to do is have the form to add new comments at the bottom of the this job "show" page. Instead of going to "/jobs/15/comments/new", I would like to have the "new comment" form in the jobs show view.